# How do I push changes to my remote repository without entering my password everytime?

Tags: git, security, github, ssh

Everytime I push changes from my local directory to a remote repo, I am prompted to enter my username and password. 
Is there a way to ignore typing the credentials for every `git push` in a particular session?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: I am using a Windows 7 and 8 machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cache your credentials so you won't be prompted to enter them every time you push: `git config --global credential.helper wincred`

> Note: Above command is for Windows.

Other operating systems and source [here](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12579867)

Comment: Thank you, that's a fair point - I will edit once I can give instructions based on operating system.

Comment: Thanks! This helps! :)